# Python development on Mac OS X: pure Mac OS or linux in virtualbox

Tags: python, macos

I'm new to Mac, and I have OS X 10.9.1. The main question is whether it is better to create a virtual machine with Linux and do port forwarding or set all packages directly to the Mac OS and work with it directly? If I create a virtual machine, I'm not sure how it will affect the health of SSD and ease of development. On the other hand, I also do not know how to affect the stability and performance of Mac OS installation packages directly into it. Surely there are some best practices, but I do not know them.

Comment: Personally I just leave `Terminal.app` open and use Sublime Text and `virtualenv` and GSD like fire. `homebrew` helps a lot too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my Mac, I use Python and PyCharm and all the usual Unix tools, and I've always done just fine. Regard OS X as a Unix machine with a very nice GUI on top of it, because it basically is -- Mac OS X is POSIX-compliant, with BSD underpinnings. Why would you even consider doing VirtualBox'd Linux? Even if you don't want to relearn the hotkeys, PyCharm provides a non-OS X mapping, and in Terminal, CTRL and ALT work like you expect.

If you're used to developing on Windows but interfacing with Unix machines through Cygwin, you'll be happy to use Terminal, which is a normal bash shell and has (or can easily get through Homebrew) all the tools you're used to. Plus the slashes go the right way and line endings don't need conversion.

If you're used to developing on a Linux distro, you'll be happy with all the things that "just work" and let you move on with your life.

So in answer to your question, do straight Mac OS X. Working in a virtualized Linux environment imparts a cost and gains you nothing.

Comment: Thank you! Before Mac OS X I developed in Ubuntu with PyCharm. I doubt Mac OS performance and stability if I had been developing on it. Can you suggest some way to organize app files in system?

Comment: "Can you suggest some way to organize app files in system?" I don't understand what you're asking, could you please rephrase it?

Comment: Oh, sorry for my bad english. I mean, how do you organize project files on your file system? On ubuntu I did it like this: "/home/user/apps/project_name/" - is an acceptable way on Mac?

Comment: On Mac there's a `/Users` directory, so you probably want something like `/Users/username/apps/project_name`, but otherwise you should be fine. Just don't forget to mark your project's Python directory in PyCharm as a source root.

And don't worry about your English, kudos to you for practicing :)

Comment: Thank you! :) I will continue to practice)

Answer (score 2):

I do all of my main development on OSX. I deploy on a linux box. Pycharm (CE) is your friend.